# What is the shortcut / How do I create function after writing it's usage in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose i have written

```
testMethod()
```

which is not in the code now. Is there any shortcut to create a method

```
func testMethod() {
}
```

In `Android Studio`, if we press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will show to create a method. I was wondering if there's any for `Xcode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No there's not any shortcut for create auto `func()` or `methods` as like as Android Studio.

**XCode** IDE does not provides any shortcuts for auto create `methods`, etc. For creating a user defined `func()` or `method()` you've compulsory write `func` keyword before of `method` name, and then **XCode** *show the suggestion for method creating* which you want e.g. **with parameters** or **without parameters** or **with/without return values**.

- You can Also **Drag and Drop** Code Snippet for methods by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Xcode is not an intelligent IDE, that's sad @Wolverian

Comment: I wish There would be such functionalists in Xcode too

Comment: There're tons of features could be added where make our life easier by increasing productivity. Apple hear us!!